# When a linear equation is written in standard form $Ax+By=C$ does $C$ have to be non-negative?

Tags: linear-algebra

When a linear equation is written in standard form $Ax+By=C$ can $C$ be negative?

ie. is it true to say that $-4x+3y=5$ is written in standard form whereas $4x-3y=-5$ is not?

Comment: $C$ can be negative, for example $$3x-4y=-3$$ you can also write $$Ax+By+C=0$$

Comment: I don't think that there is any thing called standard form of a linear equation. It all depends on the person. Some people prefer to have positive $C$, others prefer to have positive $A$ etc.

Comment: I feel like it's more standard to make sure $A$ is non-negative. Is that consistent with others' experience and/or sensibilities?

Comment: I'm guessing "standard form" is defined in your textbook, and not used by the rest of us.  So that is the place to look for your answer.

Comment: @GEdgar My question is not answered in any of my textbooks or sources. Wikipedia doesn't answer that specific question and it is not mentioned in Khan academy either.

Comment: So you are saying some textbooks use the phrase "standard form" without defining it?  I think that is a bad thing to do.  I googled and found this: http://courses.wccnet.edu/~palay/precalc/22mt01.htm ... that guy wants $A \ge 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Well I've always follow the convention of expressing the equation with A positive but there was a question in a Khan academy video today which gave 4 choices for solutions. 2 of them were something like -4x+3y=5 and 4x-3y=-5 . It would not accept the latter which is what got me thinking about this. Anway I think I'll stick with the positive A convention.

Answer (score 2):

Usually such a requirement is not implied by saying that the equation is in standard/canonical/whatever form.

If, for some particular application, it is easier for you to handle equations with non-negative $C$, then you're of course free to *set up* such a requirement yourself. (If you get an equation that doesn't satisfy it, you can just multiply both sides by $-1$).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the context. For solving linear equations by substitution, the standard form of $-4x+3y=5$ would be multiplying by $\frac{1}{4}$ to obtain
$x=\frac{3y-5}{4}$ for substitution. So the normal form could be
$$
-4x+3y-5=0,
$$

or 
$$
\; x-\frac{3}{4}y+\frac{5}{4}=0.
$$
The last normal form automatically determines the sign of the constant term.